# How to call function when page loaded odoo-14

Tags: function, odoo, pageload, odoo-14

I was trying to call a function when the page is loaded, I made some changes to the XML but none worked, for example:

```
<field name="code">action = env['res.config.settings'].set_values()</field>
```

I didn't find any viable method for odoo 14, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: can you give more details about what you want to do exactly!

Answer (score 1):

I would try custom view or custom widget. When they are started they can call server function.

For starters.

How to create new widget:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_cheatsheet.html#creating-a-new-field-widget

Or extending a wiev:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_cheatsheet.html#customizing-an-existing-view